# Error in Hadoop mv command for empty directory

Tags: hadoop

Does hadoop filesystem shell moving of empty directory?
Assume that I have a below directory which is empty.

```
hadoop fs -mv /user/abc/* /user/xyz/*
```

When I am executing the above command , it is giving me the error

> '/user/abc/*' does not exists.

However, If I put some data inside /user/abc/* , it is getting executed successfully.

Does anyone know how to handle for empty directory?

Is there any alternative to execute above command without giving error?

Comment: The abc directory needs to exist. I don't think it matters if it's empty and you use the star

Comment: It is expecting '*' in directory name if the directory is empty.

Comment: But `*` isn't a valid character for a directory. It's saying all contents of that directory, but if there's no content at all, then there's nothing to do. So the workaround would be to first check there's any data there (or `touchz` a file) before trying to move anything

Answer (score 0):

```
hadoop fs -mv /user/abc/* /user/xyz
```

The destination file doesn't need to add **/***
I thinks you want to rename the file.

you also can use this ->

```
hadoop fs -mv /user/abc /user/xyz
```

Because you xyz file is empty，so you don't got error.

but if you xyz file has many file,you will get error as well.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the errors in the question, which are about the source

Comment: There is no file in abc,so that you don't hava any file to move.no matter your in hdfs or linux. you will always got error.

Answer (score 0):

This answer should be correct I believe.

```
hadoop fs -mv /user/abc /user/xyz
```

'*' is a wild card. So it's looking for any file inside the folder. When nothing found, it returns the error.

As per the command,
When you move a file, all links to otherfiles remain intact, except when youmove it to a different file system.